# Dropwizard Migrations: dump non public schema to the migrations.xml postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, migration, liquibase, dropwizard

As mentioned in [dropwizard-migrations](http://dropwizard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/migrations.html) documentation, you can dump you existing schema to migrations.xml using command

`java -jar hello-world.jar db dump helloworld.yml`

But I am using postgresql which can have multiple schemas, so how can I configure my db to always get status/dump of the default schema i am woking on instead of public schema.

I tried changing the search_path for database but that doesn't worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase has a `defaultSchemaName` property. I haven't used dropwizard myself but it [seems](http://dropwizard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/jdbi.html) they  use JDBI and a yaml based config file for the db connection. 
So, have you tried just putting the option `defaultSchemaName` into your service configuration file like this:

```
database:
    # the name of your JDBC driver
    driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver

    # the username
    user: pg-user

    # the password
    password: iAMs00perSecrEET

    # the JDBC URL
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db.example.com/db-prod

    # any properties specific to your JDBC driver:
    properties:
        charSet: UTF-8
        defaultSchemaName: <yourSchemaName>
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't seems to work. I mean when I tried to dump the database schema, it still not returning the xml of my schema

Comment: Was worth a try. Unfortunately I don't use dropwizard myself so I can't test it myself without setting it all up. Maybe you can create a ticket on [github](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard) and ask for this to be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Jens was very close, you need to specify the `currentSchema` not `defaultSchemaName` property for the JDBC driver. like:

```
database:
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver

# the other attributes

properties:
  currentSchema: <yourSchemaName>
```